# Filling Excel sheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, for-loop, phpexcel

I am Trying to fill my Excel sheet with the data i filtered through the methods i have made. For now i am getting a sheet but i only have only one row filled not the other it's not getting the data i provide it though my object

I am trying my sheet something similar to this sheet .
[image: desired sheet]

i am trying to write code in this part of code  :

```
public function export($Sets,$disp_filter)
{

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Offic excel Test Document");
$styleArray = array(
'font'  => array(
    'bold'  => true,
    'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
    'size'  => 10,
    'name'  => 'Verdana'


));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

  $excel_out =  array($this->outputSampleName($Sets));
  // var_dump($excel_out);
  // exit;


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Sample Size and Margin of Error');
    $rowCount = 2;


    foreach ($excel_out as  $key=> $line)
    {
          $colCount = 'A';
          $i=0;
          // $line = array($Set['name']);
          // $CT = $Set['crossTabs']['base'];
          // $Moe = array($CT['sample']['moe']);

     foreach($line as  $col_value)
     {
        // var_dump($col_value);
        // exit;
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colCount.$rowCount, $col_value[$i])
         ->getStyle($colCount.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
      $colCount++;
     }
$rowCount++;
$i++;
    }
return $objPHPExcel;

}



protected function outputSampleName($Sets)
{

    foreach ($Sets as $Set)
    {
        $CT = $Set['crossTabs']['base'];
        $line = array(
            $Set['name'],

            $CT['sample']['moe'] . '%'

        );

        $excel_out []= $line;
    }

    return $excel_out;
}
```

when i see by var_dump($excel_out) 
i have this data structure :

[image]

[image: excel sheet downloaded]

**Please suggest me something how can i get those percentage values in my next row in optimized way. 
for now i can only loop through the sample[name] which are (enthusiasts, hunter, new shooters etc. )from that array. **
thanks in advance

Comment: Your variable names are confusing and also the program structure. In function `outputSampleName` the `$line` is not a line for me but a column which contains two lines. Your `$excel_out` in function `export` contains mainly an array with one element. So your first foreach will loop only one times. There the `$line` then is array(5) of 5 columns of data. In your second foreach each of the 5 `$col_value` contains a array(2) of the data [0]=>text and [1]=>percent. But you will get only [0]=>text because the first foreach will only loop one times.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, but is there any way i can loop through the both of those values in a single pair of loops... i mean here i am filling one row at a time. how can i fill second row with percent values.

Comment: First step will be not to wrap the result of `$this->outputSampleName($Sets)` into an array again but to take it as it is. Then try again and try to understand how the foreach work.

Comment: oh yes , you are right . well i can't post photo in comments please look at the post below.